# Docker-compose: connections between https express servers

Tags: node.js, sockets, docker

Two Express servers are running within docker containers under docker-compose.

```
version: '2'
services:
  server-1:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/www
      - /www/node_modules
  server-2:
    build: ../server-2
    links:
      - api-server
    volumes:
      - ../server-2/:/www
      - /www/node_modules
```

`server-2` connects to `server-1` through socket connection with this address: `http://server-1:8080` (socket.io library).
Everything works perfect.

But if i'm trying to use `https` module instead of `http` inside `server-1`, then `server-2` can't connect to it. I've tried pretty much all variations of changing ports (8080 to 443 etc) and changing socket connection address protocol from `http` to `https`.

Only one variable persists all the time: i can run server on any port with `http` and connection being established, but once it changed to `https`, it stops connecting.

Comment: have you added ssl certificate as well?

Comment: yep, certificate works fine, server is available on `https://server_url.com`, connection secured